# Pure translation + Pure rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Can a body moving in helical path said to be in pure rotation and pure translation simultaneously because for pure rotation ( if I'm not wrong) the rigid body should be rotating about a FIXED axes (which is satisfied in case of helical path) and for pure translation 'The line connecting two particles of rigid body should remain parallel to itself during the motion '? Are my definitions for pure rotation and pure translation correct?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to talk about 'pure' rotations and translations since the motion of a body depends on the reference frame of the observer. An object that is rotating about a fixed axis will look like it's moving in a helix from the perspective of an observer that is moving with certain speed in a straight line parallel to the rotation axis.

Comment: @NalinYadav It does make sense to study motion, after you decide what your frame of reference is.